# What is the best way to do download stream the file from the server(download-server or s3 or any cloud server)?

Tags: php, laravel

What is the best way to do download stream  the file from the server(download-server or s3 or any cloud server)?

How to download a music file from the server (cloud) with FTP-stream  and send it to stream client(i use laravel)?

Is this the right way?

How much does it take to RAM and CPU? When the number of clients is high, it's not a problem for a server with RAM 3G?

The file size is about 6 to 200 MB and use laravel and Storage and ftp.

Could someone please give me some direction on this topic? Thanks.